# Problema com CASE WHEN SQL-SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT CASE WHEN VALOR > 0 THEN
VALOR ELSE
"Não tem"
END AS NOMECOLUNA
FROM BLABLABLA
```

Estou tendo um erro onde não é possível converter "não tem" para int.

A questão é que eu queria que retornasse escrito que não tem quando o inteiro for 0...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode converter o numérico para `VARCHAR` já que todos os resultados do `CASE` devem ter o mesmo tipo:

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN VALOR > 0 THEN CAST(VALOR AS VARCHAR)
         ELSE 'Não tem'
       END AS NOMECOLUNA
  FROM BLABLABLA
```

Comment: Valeu cara! era isso mesmo! Eu estava tentando colocar o cast na validação, mas deveria colocar na resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Dentro do Case no SQL não é possível gerar uma coluna com valores numéricos e de texto como uma resposta só.

Ou seja, no seu código se o VALOR for maior que 0 ele gera um resultado numerico e caso seja menor que 0 gera um valor de texto.

Pensei em 2 soluções possíveis:

1- Gerar uma coluna separada da de valor:

```
SELECT 
VALOR,
CASE WHEN VALOR > 0 THEN
"Com Valor" ELSE
"Não tem"
END AS NOMECOLUNA
FROM BLABLABLA
```

2- Gerar o resultado com valores de texto para todos os casos (transformar numero em texto):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN VALOR > 0 THEN
Put(VALOR, "numero de caracteres") ELSE
"Não tem"
END AS NOMECOLUNA
FROM BLABLABLA
```

Comment: Vou dar um voto positivo pelos caminhos alternativos, mas a outra resposta ficou mais correta.